# VBA Range.Find procedure - can't find Type Mismatch

Tags: excel, vba

I'm working on a database for my workplace, which is the Outreach department of a large science center. We have a lot of schools that violate our (pretty specific) contract, so we're looking to track and reduce these violations.

To cut down on misspellings that would make searching the database later more difficult, I want the user (when entering a new school) to pull up the Userform, enter the name of their school, then click a search button to populate a listbox with the names of schools that match what they entered. If they click on a school in that list, the form uses that as the school name. If not, it prompts them to enter a new school name.

My code is pretty basic right now. I'm trying to use a Find & FindNext procedure to pull up all instances of a school name, but I'm getting a Type Mismatch error (#13) with the code I have currently and I can't find where that might come from. I've checked that no variables or Userform objects are misspelled.

I want the Find function to return only the Range of the first cell, so that I can turn it into .Address or .Value as needed.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub cbtnSearchSchool_Click()

Dim lrow As Long
Dim schoolmatch As Range

'defines "lrow" as the last completely empty row in the table
lrow = Cells.find(What:="", _
        After:=Range("A1"), _
        LookIn:=xlValues, _
        LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
        SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False, _
        SearchFormat:=False).Row

Range("A1").Activate

'defines "schoolmatch" variable as the first school in the list that
'matches what was entered in the text box.
Set schoolmatch = Range("SchoolName").find(What:=txtbSchoolName.Value, _
    After:=ActiveCell, _
    LookIn:=xlValues, _
    LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
    SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False, _
    SearchFormat:=False)

'returns value of first found cell to check for accuracy
MsgBox schoolmatch.Value
```

[This is a photo of the Userform if anybody would like to see it.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gSF3a.png)

Edit: Sorry, I actually dimensioned schoolmatch as a Range originally and just changed it to Object while I was debugging - I got the same error before and after changing it.

It shows me the line I'm getting the error on - it's the `Set schoolmatch = Range.Find` operation, but I can't figure out anywhere that I would be mixing up data types. I have a SchoolName range that I've double-checked, and I've checked all of the other variable names for misspellings.

Over time there will be thousands of schools on this list, so this search function is necessary to filter some results before users select a school on the form.

Comment: lRow is defined as a `Long` but you are trying to set it equal to a `Range` object.

Comment: @braX How and where?

Comment: @braX your statement is wrong, since there is `.Row` at the end of `range` which makes it is numeric and not range, who upvoted that should be downvoted himself

Comment: It doesn't show you the line the error occurs on? Also, you do have a `SchoolName` named range, correct?  As for `lrow`, perhaps skip using `Find` and do `Range("A"&Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row`, or use `xlDown` from `A1`, if it's contiguous data and you have gaps where there are other things you don't consider part of the table.)  Also, `SchoolMatch` should be a **`Range`**, not `Object` I believe. That may be causing an error.

Comment: @LindyNewman use F8 to run and it will run it line by line and the moment that it is executing the problematic line it will throw the error, that way you can tell us which line is the problem

Comment: Why not change it to a combobox and set the RowSource to your list of schools in the worksheet.  This would eliminate any need for them to type in the name.  They select it from your list.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the use of `Object` may be causing the error.  Also, with a slight tweak to how `lRow` is assigned, this should run better:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub cbtnSearchSchool_Click()

Dim lrow As Long
Dim schoolmatch As Range

'defines "lrow" as the last completely empty row in the table
lrow = Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row

'defines "schoolmatch" variable as the first school in the list that
'matches what was entered in the text box.
Set schoolmatch = Range("SchoolName").find(What:=txtbSchoolName.Value, _
    After:=ActiveCell, _
    LookIn:=xlValues, _
    LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
    SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False, _
    SearchFormat:=False)

'returns value of first found cell to check for accuracy
MsgBox schoolmatch.Value
```

A note with `lRow`, if say cell `A100` is empty but `B100` isn't, it will improperly assign that row (row `100`) as the last row.

If you really need to make sure this doesn't happen (same with your OP), you could loop through all rows until a blank.  Like this perhaps:

```
lRow = 1
Do While WorksheetFunction.CountA(Rows(lRow)) <> 0
    lRow  = lRow  + 1
Loop
Debug.print "Last row is: " & lRow
```